7600W generator to 7500W transfer switch?
House has Reliance Controls 30310A Pro/Tran transfer switch installed.
Its spec says 'For generators up to 7500 Running Watts'
Is it ok to connect a Predator 7600W Running Inverter Generator generator to it ?
Or would it be better to stick to 7000W Running Inverter Generator ?
The house has gas furnace & water heater, air conditioning will not be used.



The instructions say up to and max watts that are allowed and you have to go by that. 7600w is over what is allowed, so insurance can refuse any claims.

So long as the generator has a 30A outlet with a 30A breaker, it is ok to use the larger generator.  (Although I question your need for the larger generator given what your label says is fed by it, and the significantly higher price for marginally higher power).
Go by the transfer switch installation manual, not the Amazon marketing which is where you see the "7500 Watt Generator" text.  Most portable generators over 7200W, even 7500W ones, also have a 50A outlet so you can squeeze out every last watt.   Just don't use that, and make sure the generator outlet you do use has a 30A breaker on it.
That breaker will also protect the cabling from your generator to the transfer switch, all of which is probably also rated for 30A.
